# second legend in R in XY plot

Tags: r, lattice

I want to make a second legend in my XY plot. I have made a XYplot with three different groups in it. I already maked one legend, but I want to make a second legend in which a want to show the Multiple R-squared value and the P value. I have tried several things but it doesn't work. below you can see what I put in R.

```
palette(rainbow(3))

library(lattice)

xyplot(ampli...freq~m.s,groups=pleo.,data=data,type=c("g","p","r"),pch=16,cex=1.1,lwd=2,col=palette(),
xlab="Flowspeed (m/s)",ylab="Amplitude*Frequency",main="Lobster Stephan, amplitude*Frequency against the flowspeed",

key=list(space="right",points=list(pch=16,cex=1.0,col=palette()),
text=list(c("pleopode 2","pleopode 3","pleopode 4")),

legend=list(space="inside",lines=list(lwt=2,col=palette()),
text=list(c("r2= ","R2 = ","R2 =")))))
```

Can anybody tell me how I can make this wright?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`legend` overrides `auto.key`. You should create a first plot with a keey/auto.key and update it.

```
myplot <- xyplot(...)
fun_legend <- function(txt,x,...) grid::textGrob(txt, x=x,...)
update(my_plot, 
           legend = list(inside =list(fun = "fun_legend",
                                      args=list(txt='some text',x=4,rot=90))))
```